# Text in "Values" of Pivot Table fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I created a PIVOT Table and I would like to display strings in the `values` columns. However, when I add a column with strings to the `values` only the `count` is displayed which is always 1 for 1 string. Is it possible to display text?

[image]

Comment: Yes, if you have Power Pivot (using a `concatenatex` measure); no, if you don't.

Comment: You'd also be able to display the Text, if instead of adding it as a Value, you added it as a Column, but that would depend on what you are trying to achieve...